# Let $f(x)$ be irreducible in the rationals so that the order of $\operatorname{Gal}(f(x))$ is $255$. Show that $f(x)$ is solvable by radicals.

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, sylow-theory, solvable-groups

I know that $f(x)$ is solvable by radicals $\iff \def\Gal{\text{Gal}}\Gal(f(x))$ is solvable, so I began by trying to find what $\Gal(f(x))$ is. Let $G = \Gal(f(x)).$

Since $|G|= 255 = (3)(5)(17)$, I tried to show that all of the Sylow p-subgroups are normal, so $G$ is isomorphic to $Z_{255}$ and is, therefore, solvable. However, not all of the subgroups are necessarily normal -- $H_{17}$ is and either $H_3$ or $H_5$ is, but not necessarily both. So $G$ is not necessarily isomorphic to $Z_{255}$.

Am I thinking about this correctly? I feel like I'm correct in thinking that I need to find $G$ to show that it's solvable, but I'm questioning whether Sylow p-subgroups are the way to go. Is there a simpler way to find what $G$ is?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Every group of odd order is soluble.

Comment: You can mod out the known normal subgroup $H_{17}$. The quotient group is of order fifteen, and [therefore cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/67407/11619).

Comment: I failed to find an example of a non-abelian group of order 255. Then I proved to myself that such things don't exist. Luckily I don't have to type it here because [we've done it already](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/255441/11619).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groups of order $pqr$ for primes $p<q<r$ are solvable:

[Group of order $pqr$, $p < q < r$ primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442289/group-of-order-pqr-p-q-r-primes)

Hence the Galois groups is solvable, so that $f$ is solvable by radicals.